# How extensive is OpenLayers support for KML?

Tags: openlayers

I see from examples that OpenLayers supports KML.  When I look at the KML docs I see very extensive functionality, and am wondering if OL supports all these capabilities?  I.e., if I see a capability in KML as described by Google, can I simply assume that this will work in an OL map?  If not, what are is the extent of the support?  I have looked at the OL documentation but I only see very sparse mention of KML.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the short answer is YES, openlayers reads KML quite well.

while not every functionality will work exactly as in google earth, the basics (most of what works with google MAPS) are not a problem: styles, icons, polygons, linestrings, markers, folders, cdata, description and name tags work perfectly well.

post your kml to a website and use these sites to compare the results:

http://maps.burningsilicon.net/

and to view your kml in googlemaps change the URL parameter (www.yourURL.com)

https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http://www.yourURL.com

ps: having a hard time implementing icon offsets with kml maps in openlayers.